# Rails/ spec fill_in using placeholder

Tags: rspec

In my rspec test, how do I fill_in a text field using Placeholder. I cannot use id and name as they are auto generated for the nested form.

```
<input class="input-medium inline" id="user_kids_attributes_new_1342116887461_first_name" name="user[kids_attributes][new_1342116887461][first_name]" placeholder="First Name" size="30" type="text">
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Placeholder support will be in the next version of Capybara. For now, try:

```
find("input[placeholder='First Name']").set "value"
```

Answer (score 9):

There is also another way:

```
fill_in :placeholder => "Fill in some text", :with => "Text"
```

Comment: From at least version Capybara 2.3 (maybe earlier) fill_in finds placeholder text.

Comment: `Capybara 2.5`, you should not specify `placeholder` key but use it like `fill_in "placeholder name", with: "text"`

Answer (score 0):

`'Card number'` being the placeholder

This should work, **EXCEPT** you're trying to fill an input **inside an iframe**

In that case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53227758/1248725

```
fill_in('Card number', with: "#{arg1} #{arg2} #{arg3} #{arg4}")
```

This