# Capybara How to use within_frame for the only iframe in the page without id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iframe, cucumber, capybara

I have an  in the the page that I need to test with Cucumber and Capybara, the iframe does not have a class or id attribute but it's the only iframe on the DOM. How can I use the `within_frame` capybara method?

Answer (score 3):

use `find` to get the element and pass it to the `within_frame` method.

```
iframe = find('iframe')
within_frame(iframe) do
 # expect something here
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a recent version of Capybara the locator argument to `within_frame` is optional if there's only one iframe on the page

```
within_frame do
  # blah blah
end
```

Comment: That's a nice improvement! I'm stuck with an old version, but good to know.

Comment: @juliangonzalez Depending on how old a version you're using you may just be able to pass `nil` as the locator to have it default to finding any frame `within_frame nil do ... end` or by frame index  `within_frame 0 do ... end`